# React Router direct url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router

I have a react app (with router) that I built and that I use statically on a Node.JS server.

I can navigate inside the app thanks to the internal links (Link & Navlink) but if I enter a url directly, I get the following message

```
/home/deploy/www/mydomain.fr/production/releases/20181205130322/client/index.html
```

This is my config to render builded react-app as static files

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.send(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'index.html'));
});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `res.sendFile(...)`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you very much for your answer, you are the best ;-)